# C++ Gmock - WillOnce - Can you do anything aside from return a value?

Tags: c++, qt, googlemock

I am learning gmock and wondering how I can make my mock object do something when one of the mocked methods is called.

I need to mock some interfaces that make use of Qt and I am trying to get Qt and Gmock to work together.

For example, I mocked a network socket interface class, gave it to a network client class via constructor based DI, and I want to tell the mock socket to call one of its methods to signal the client when connection completes, in order to pretend a connection was made.

I see there is `WillOnce` and it takes and "action" but the documentation I am reading doesn't really explain what kinds of things an "action" can be. All the examples simply return something or increment a global variable. Can you call methods belonging to the abstract class you are mocking?

If not, I see you can separately define a fake object and make it a member of the mock, and then delegate, but that seems like a hell of a lot of work to put into every test case that wants a different behavior.

- You have to define every single pure virtual in your interface whether you want to use it or not for that particular test case
- It seems I will have to create different fakes and therefore different mocks local to each test case, when the fake behavior differs
  ... For example, maybe I want open to signal in one test case a and not to signal in another

Here is a bit of example code:

```
class MySocketInterface : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
   
       virtual void connect(std::string url) = 0;
       
    signal:    // Specific to Qt, but this is what I need to call
       // Notifies subscribers
       void connected();
 }

 class MyThingToTest
 {
 public:
     MyThingToTest(std::unique_ptr<MySocketInterface> && socket);
     void connect(std::string url);
     State getState() const;
 private:
     std::unique_ptr<MySocketInterface> m_socket;
     // Changes state to connected
     void onConnected();
 }

 Test1:
 ) Make a mock socket
 ) Give it to MyThingToTest
 ) Call MyThingToTest::connect
 ) mock socket needs to send notification faking connecting by calling `emit connected`
 ) Check if MyThingToTest is in connected state

 Test2:
 ) Make a mock socket
 ) Give it to MyThingToTest
 ) Call MyThingToTest::connect
 ) mock socket needs to not send notification, and 30 seconds needs to elapse.
 ) Check if MyThingToTest is in an error state
```

I want to prevent having to define an entirely new fake class and mock that delegates to it every single unit test case where actions would differ.

Please note, I am not looking for QSignalSpy or to verify signals and slots. I want to verify the functionality of my classes that react to them and have those classes use mock dependencies so I don't have to talk across the real network.

Comment: A lot of default actions are provide and you can do many things with them: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/reference/actions.md

Maybe it would help for you to update your question with an outline of the test you are conceptually trying to write.

Comment: I just do: `WillOnce(Invoke(<lambda here which returs proper value and does other stuff>))`

Comment: @Marek R but the lambda can't call a method on the interface you are mocking, can it?

Comment: lambda can call anything as far as you did proper capture of variables.

Comment: @Marek R I don't think it can call private methods of your interface that you are mocking. If you can get it to do so, would love to mark some example code as an answer.

Comment: If you have private methods then this is not an interface! Also this detail is for another question.

Comment: Anyway `MySocketInterface` can't have a signal, since signals and slots in Qt are correct only for `QObjects` which have `Q_OBJECT` macro in top of definition!

Comment: Yea, I guess this question is going to be specific to using Gmock with Qt and that combination is going to have a very small audience :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `InvokeWithoutArgs` to achieve the result that you are looking for, assuming that you are using Qt 5 or greater.  Your mock object should be defined as follows:

```
class MockMySocketInterface : public MySocketInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MockMySocketInterface() { }
    virtual ~MockMySocketInterface() { }

    MOCK_METHOD1(connect, void(std::string));
};
```

Your test would look something like the following:

```
auto socket = std::make_unique<MockMySocketInterface>(); // Could also use NiceMock here.

// This could alternately be an EXPECT_CALL, but you would need to use WillOnce
// or WillRepeatedly instead of WillByDefault.
ON_CALL(*socket, connect(_))
    .WillByDefault(InvokeWithoutArgs(socket.get(), &MockMySocketInterface::connected));
MyThingToTest thing(socket);

// etc.
```

Comment: You are the awesome sauce.